# How to call an API in HTTPS with React-Admin data provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, dataprovider

I'm new in the back-end world and I'm trying to create an admin backoffice with React-Admin, except that I have trouble choosing the dataProvider.

I have a MySQL Express API, which I developed locally so I use Simple REST Data Provider, but it doesn't support HTTPS protocol?

I try to put in production my back-office linked to my api in https://___.org but I have "a communication error with the server".

Isn't it not advisable to use http for such sensitive requests? How can I make requests to my API in a secure way while remaining in harmony with React-Admin?

Comment: I use Simple REST Data Provider over HTTP without any issue, it works. I don't have a difference of code between HTTP and HTTPS.

Are you sure you set-up the backend as HTTPS ? What does the web browser network tool displays ?

Could it be a "blocked mixed content" case ? Your browser blocks HTTP requests from a HTTPS page ?

Comment: @Ricola3D Finally, my hosting encountered an SSL problem at the same time which created confusion and I thought that the protocol was not supported. Finally it works perfectly (I finally use JSON Server)